# c pthreads: run at most 4 threads concurrently at any time

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program in C, which takes arbitrary number of files as commandline argument, and calculates sha1sum for every file. I am using pthreads, so that I can take advantage of all 4 my cores.

Currently, my code runs all threads in parallel at the same time. 
Here is a snippet:

```
c = 0;
for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
    if (pthread_create(&t[c], NULL, &sha1sum, (void *) argv[n])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    c++;
}

c = 0;
for (n = optind; n < argc; n++) {
    pthread_join(t[c], NULL);
    c++;
}
```

Obviously, it is not efficient (or scalable) to start all threads at once.

What would be the best way to make sure, that only 4 threads are running at any time? Somehow I need to start 4 threads at the beginning, and then "replace" a thread with new one as soon as it completes.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously, it is not efficient (or scalable) to start all threads at once.

Creating 4 threads is not necessarily provides the best performance on a 4 core machine. If the threads are doing IO or waiting on something, then creating more than 4 threads could also result in better performance/efficiency. You just need to figure out an approximate number based on the work your threads do and possbily a mini-benchmark.

Regardless of what number you choose (i.e. number of threads), what you are looking for is a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). The idea is to create a fixed number of threads and feed them work as soon as they complete.

See [C: What's the way to make a poolthread with pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954489/c-whats-the-way-to-make-a-poolthread-with-pthreads) for a simple skeleton. This [repo](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool) also shows a self-contained example (check the license if you are going to use it). You can find many similar examples online.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is a `semaphore`; it will allow you to restrict only 4 threads to be running at a time.  You would/could start them all up initially, and it will take care of letting a new one proceed when a running one finishes.